# How To Read Read Custom Post Type Data in Headless CMS Mode

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, rest-api

I'm doing my site with two pieces -- the headless CMS on a subdomain where content is entered, and the root domain where I display data. Only WP is installed in the subdomain, not the root domain. In the subdomain, I created a custom post type called Staff, and then items inside are a Member. I noticed that I can't use the URL...

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

([WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/))

...to read these items. Looking in the docs, I see that I can address it as...

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/staff

When I use /staff, it shows me the core post fields, but not any of the custom field groups. (Note, I'm using the Custom Post Types plugin from TotalPress.org.)

How do I get a given staff member's custom field properties on their record? I can access someone such as:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/staff/?slug=john-smith

...but there are no custom fields in there that I attached to this record.

How do I use the REST API to get the custom fields attached to a custom post type?

Comment: have you declared that they're available via rest api when registering? There is no code in your question

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm using the Custom Post Types plugin from TotalPress.org, which saves me the coding. It is doing the registering. I also figured out why the /staff wasn't working in the API -- it was how I declared it. I'll be editing this post on that part, at least. I just can't get the custom fields.

Comment: I thought you had used it then abandoned it based on your question. 3rd party plugin support is off topic here. This is not a place to get help with the Custom Post Types plugin.

Comment: Of note, the canonical answer to this is to ensure permalinks are flushed and the CPT in question has `show_in_rest` set to true, but because you used a plugin to build your post types that solution is unavailable to you. Having said that, custom post types are straight forward and there are code generators online that write the code for you based on inputs and checkboxes. You don't need a plugin to auto-register post types for you

Comment: And you have to register meta to have it show up in the REST API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix without code. I installed the [Rest API Helper Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-helper/) and it now exposed the custom fields on a given post type.

Comment: interesting definition of "without code", maybe you ment "without writting any code by myself" :)

Comment: just be aware that the plugin doesn't seem to be maintained. might still work properly for a long time but you are taking a risk

Comment: @MarkKaplun 'without code I did by myself' -- yes, you are correct there. And thanks for the other advice.